# Conda proxy configuration

Tags: windows, anaconda

Is it possible to set up Conda's configuration file (.condarc) in windows so that the current user's credentials are automatically sent to the proxys defined in proxy_servers when HTTP requests are issued?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You first need to find out where the .condarc file may be created. The easiest way of doing this is to set a variable and see where the resultant file is saved like this:

```
conda config --set use_pip True
```

You should probably have a .condarc file at this point in C:\Users\

Edit it to add the proxying stanza:

proxy_servers:
    http: http://my.proxy.server.url/

and so on.